# Positioning RSS feed when linking to an external Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an external Javascript file that I have linked to my html file. The positioning works fine until I try to use an external Javascript file. The RSS feed goes to the top of my page when I link in the head. Can I put the link anywhere on my html file or does it have to be in the head. I want the RSS feed to be under the "newsfeed" id. I also left out some of the info for my page because I only need to show the div and css.

Here's my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>GamerZone</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="icon/ico" href="images/icon.ico" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="rss-feed.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
    <div id="allcontent">
        <div id="banner">
            <a target="_self" href="index.html" title="">
            <img src="images/banner.jpg" border="0" alt="GamerZone Banner">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="nav-home">
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-games"> 
                <a href="games.html">Games</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-chat">
                <a href="chat.html">Chat</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-suggestions">
                <a href="suggestions.html">Suggestions</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="newsfeed">
            //RSS feed goes here
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my css code:

```
#allcontent {
    width: 1000px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background-color: ;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#poll {
    background-color: white;
    float: left;
    padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
    margin: 15px 10px 10px 22px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
}

#newsfeed {
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

Here's my Javascript code:

```
<!-- 
rssfeed_url = new Array();   
rssfeed_url[0]="http://news.yahoo.com/rss/gaming";
rssfeed_frame_width="500"; 
rssfeed_frame_height="720"; 
rssfeed_scroll="on"; 
rssfeed_scroll_step="6"; 
rssfeed_scroll_bar="on"; 
rssfeed_target="_blank"; 
rssfeed_font_size="14"; 
rssfeed_font_face=""; 
rssfeed_border="on";
rssfeed_css_url="http://example.com/newsfeed.css";
rssfeed_title="on"; 
rssfeed_title_name=""; 
rssfeed_title_bgcolor="#3366ff"; 
rssfeed_title_color="#fff"; 
rssfeed_title_bgimage="http://"; 
rssfeed_footer="off"; 
rssfeed_footer_name="rss feed"; 
rssfeed_footer_bgcolor="#fff"; 
rssfeed_footer_color="#333"; 
rssfeed_footer_bgimage="http://"; 
rssfeed_item_title_length="50"; 
rssfeed_item_title_color="#666"; 
rssfeed_item_bgcolor="#fff"; 
rssfeed_item_bgimage="http://"; 
rssfeed_item_border_bottom="on"; 
rssfeed_item_source_icon="off"; 
rssfeed_item_date="off"; 
rssfeed_item_description="on"; 
rssfeed_item_description_length="120"; 
rssfeed_item_description_color="#666"; 
rssfeed_item_description_link_color="#333"; 
rssfeed_item_description_tag="off"; 
rssfeed_no_items="0"; 
rssfeed_cache = "7872565d53aadc6c14b4ab1bb3f79bdb"; 
//--> 

(function(){
var a=window;
var b="";
for(i=0;i<a.rssfeed_url.length;i++) {
    b=b+"rssfeed[url]["+i+"]="+encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_url[i])+"&"
}
var c="http://feed.surfing-waves.com/php/rssfeed.php"+"?"+b+"rssfeed[type]="+(a.rssfeed_type?a.rssfeed_type:"")+"&rssfeed[frame_width]="+a.rssfeed_frame_width+"&rssfeed[frame_height]="+a.rssfeed_frame_height+"&rssfeed[scroll]="+(a.rssfeed_scroll?a.rssfeed_scroll:"")+"&rssfeed[scroll_step]="+(a.rssfeed_scroll_step?a.rssfeed_scroll_step:"")+"&rssfeed[scroll_bar]="+(a.rssfeed_scroll_bar?a.rssfeed_scroll_bar:"")+"&rssfeed[target]="+(a.rssfeed_target?a.rssfeed_target:"")+"&rssfeed[font_size]="+(a.rssfeed_font_size?a.rssfeed_font_size:"")+"&rssfeed[font_face]="+(a.rssfeed_font_face?a.rssfeed_font_face:"")+"&rssfeed[border]="+(a.rssfeed_border?a.rssfeed_border:"")+"&rssfeed[css_url]="+(a.rssfeed_css_url?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_css_url):"")+"&rssfeed[title]="+(a.rssfeed_title?a.rssfeed_title:"")+"&rssfeed[title_name]="+(a.rssfeed_title_name?a.rssfeed_title_name:"")+"&rssfeed[title_bgcolor]="+(a.rssfeed_title_bgcolor?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_title_bgcolor):"")+"&rssfeed[title_color]="+(a.rssfeed_title_color?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_title_color):"")+"&rssfeed[title_bgimage]="+(a.rssfeed_title_bgimage?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_title_bgimage):"")+"&rssfeed[footer]="+(a.rssfeed_footer?a.rssfeed_footer:"")+"&rssfeed[footer_name]="+(a.rssfeed_footer_name?a.rssfeed_footer_name:"")+"&rssfeed[footer_bgcolor]="+(a.rssfeed_footer_bgcolor?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_footer_bgcolor):"")+"&rssfeed[footer_color]="+(a.rssfeed_footer_color?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_footer_color):"")+"&rssfeed[footer_bgimage]="+(a.rssfeed_footer_bgimage?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_footer_bgimage):"")+"&rssfeed[item_bgcolor]="+(a.rssfeed_item_bgcolor?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_item_bgcolor):"")+"&rssfeed[item_bgimage]="+(a.rssfeed_item_bgimage?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_item_bgimage):"")+"&rssfeed[item_title_length]="+(a.rssfeed_item_title_length?a.rssfeed_item_title_length:"")+"&rssfeed[item_title_color]="+(a.rssfeed_item_title_color?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_item_title_color):"")+"&rssfeed[item_border_bottom]="+(a.rssfeed_item_border_bottom?a.rssfeed_item_border_bottom:"")+"&rssfeed[item_source_icon]="+(a.rssfeed_item_source_icon?a.rssfeed_item_source_icon:"")+"&rssfeed[item_date]="+(a.rssfeed_item_date?a.rssfeed_item_date:"")+"&rssfeed[item_description]="+(a.rssfeed_item_description?a.rssfeed_item_description:"")+"&rssfeed[item_description_length]="+(a.rssfeed_item_description_length?a.rssfeed_item_description_length:"")+"&rssfeed[item_description_color]="+(a.rssfeed_item_description_color?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_item_description_color):"")+"&rssfeed[item_description_link_color]="+(a.rssfeed_item_description_link_color?encodeURIComponent(a.rssfeed_item_description_link_color):"")+"&rssfeed[item_description_tag]="+(a.rssfeed_item_description_tag?a.rssfeed_item_description_tag:"")+"&rssfeed[no_items]="+(a.rssfeed_no_items?a.rssfeed_no_items:"")+"&rssfeed[cache]="+(a.rssfeed_cache?a.rssfeed_cache:"");
if(a.rssfeed_border!="off"&&!a.rssfeed_css_url){}
document.write('<iframe name="rssfeed_frame" width="'+a.rssfeed_frame_width+'" height="'+a.rssfeed_frame_height+'" frameborder="0" src="'+c+'" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" scrolling="no" ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="true"></iframe>')
})()
```

If any additional information is needed please ask before rejecting my question.
Also, for future reference, is there a way to format everything right without hitting space a million times? If this counts as an extra question and isn't allowed then disregard. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script uses `document.write` so you should put the `script` pointing to the RSS JavaScript in `<div id="newsfeed">`. That script is generating an `IFRAME` that I assume surfing-waves.com is transforming into HTML, so putting it in the `HEAD` will write the `IFRAME` in the `HEAD`, which you should definitely avoid. So, remove `<script type="text/javascript" src="rss-feed.js"></script>` from the `HEAD` and move it into `<div id="newsfeed">` like this:

```
<div id="newsfeed">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="rss-feed.js"></script>
</div>
```

If you wanted to associate the RSS feed as an alternate form of this page, then you would use the `LINK` element to refer to it, but that doesn't apply here. In this case you just want to display those items in your page.

Comment: That was a stupid question I guess. The only other issue is that my comp sci prof said that links to Javascript files should be in the head. Although, if your way is fine then I'll just use that.

Comment: When the browser interprets a javascript file, it basically just inserts it into the html as if it were a script block at the place where it was linked from. If that javascript file is doing stuff that doesn't make sense in the head section, then the file shouldn't be linked from there. document.write() outputs html at the point in the document where the code is running, if it's adding code that should be in the body, then your script should be in the body.